# How to get familyName and givenName in google plus?

Tags: symfony, google-api, google-plus, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I am using HWIOAuthBundle for retrieving data from google+ api. For that, I extended FOSUBUserProvider class and I rewrote the  `public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response) {}` as follows:

```
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response) {
    // some check
    // ...
    // getting the attributes for the google+ api
    $attr = $response->getResponse();

    // creating and setting my user
    $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
    $user->$setter_id($username);
    $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());

    $user->setEmail($response->getEmail());
    $user->setEmailCanonical($response->getEmail());
    if (isset($attr['gender'])) {
        if ($attr['gender'] == 'male')
            $user->setGoogleGender(true);
        else
            $user->setGoogleGender(false);
        }
        if (isset($attr['birthday'])) {
            $user->setGoogleBirthday(new \DateTime($attr['birthday']));
        }
        if (isset($attr['name'])) {
            // $attr['name'] contains displayName (givenName and familyName together)
        }

return $user;
}
```

This is how is defined the person in google+.

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "XXXX",
 "gender": "male",
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "9999999999999",
 "displayName": "Jule Dupond",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Dupond",
  "givenName": "Jule"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/9999999",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://....",
  "isDefault": true
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 1,
 "verified": false
}
```

My goal is **simply** to retrieve `givenName` and `familyName`.

Thank you for giving me an idea!

Comment: $attr['name']['givenName'] ?

Comment: I have already tried that but with no success!!!

Comment: print_r($attr) yields?

Comment: This is my biggest problem. Writing print_r($attr) in the service `FOSUBUserProvider` will not be displayed! Have you any idea to get it in the log at least? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I checked the log file and there is nothing on `$attr`. Should I write a service for generating log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. To get familyName and givenName, you just need this: `$attr['given_name']` and `$attr['family_name']`.

Hope it will help others...